# Batch Run Pandas Concat Script multiple times in a directory containing many subfolders containing CSVs

Tags: python, pandas

Good afternoon,

I have a python pandas concat script that horizontally merges 2 CSVs into a 'master.csv' and renames one of the CSVs headers in the merged master.csv. I currently have a directory containing 100 sub-folders with two CSVs in each (all csvs have the same file name: csv1, csv2). I want to batch run the pandas concat script over each subfolder in the main directory. I am assuming I need some sort of loop but am still inexperienced with python and pandas. Any help would be appreciated!

Script below:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")

b.rename(index=str, columns={'month' : 'month - 2018','year' : 'year - 2018', inplace=True)

b = b.reset_index(drop=True)

merged = pd.concat([a,b], axis=1, sort=False)

merged.to_csv("Master.csv", index=False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked out `os.walk()`?

Comment: @AHayser you want to save master file inside each subfolder or create master file outside?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Yes, create the master file inside each subfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MattR for recommending os.walk(). I was able to run my script through each subdirectory successfully. I had to change my working directory each time the script ran, then moved onto the next subdir. Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def Merge_CSVs():

rootdir = "/mypath"

directories = [os.path.abspath(x[0]) for x in os.walk(rootdir)]
directories.remove(os.path.abspath(rootdir))

for i in directories:
    os.chdir(i)
    Merge_CSVs()
```